# Get Set properties in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, properties

I am very new to .net .. I want to know What is Get, Set Properties ? I can't understand this? Please could anyone help me with some examples?

Comment: I think you're gonna get downvotes. Some people will ask you "what have you tried?", and some will suggest you, "try to do something, when you are stuck, come here and write your problem, this is not a tutorial website". But I am also curious what people write here.

Comment: I agree this isn't a tutorial website, but it is a site for information. That information can be anything, but most important to this user, is he gets directed to the specific place to find his answer. Whether its something simple of complicated, he still needs our help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Get is called Accessor and Set is called Mutators in .Net

in Oops to preserve DataAbstraction concept we keeps Data member private in class.
now to access that data members from outside world we need some mechanism through which we can use it.
for this we define property which contains Accessor and Mutator.
with this we can give tremendous data abstraction.

you need them to have control over your object private fields values. for example if you don't wanna allow nulls or negative values for integers. Also, encapsulation is useful for triggering events on change of values of object members. Example

```
bool started;
public bool Started
{
    get { return started; }
    set
    {
        started = value;
        if (started)
            OnStarted(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}
```

another example

```
int positiveNumber;

public int PositiveNumber
{
    get { return positiveNumber; }
    set {
        if (value < 0)
            positiveNumber = 0;
        else positiveNumber = value;
    }
}
```

and also another implementation of read only properties could be as follows

```
int positiveNumber;

public int PositiveNumber
{
    get { return positiveNumber; }

}
```

Comment: I would also stress the use of `public int PositiveNumber { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 0):

These are mutator method's, check Wikipedia for example and explanation, don't have to copy/paste that ;)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method

Answer (score 0):

You use properties as part of classes to store data.

```
public class MyClass
{
    string ClassName { get; set;}
}
```

If you instantiate this class, you will be able to set its `ClassName` field.

These properties are then used within the class for methods to manipulate.

The `Set` will allow modification of the property. The `Get` will allow extraction of the data from the property. They are for property access.

I suggest you read some intro books on c# / vb.net to understand how to program first.

This will then enable you to understand more about what you asking.